# Android studio gradle Exception

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I have a problem while compiling in the gradle, this is my code, I can not find solution.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this issue?

My project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } 
}
```

---

My module level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rootdev.khroga"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://swisscodemonkeys.github.io/appbrain-sdk/maven'
        }
    }
} 
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'

    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.appbrain:appbrain-applift-sdk:10.51'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

---

And the error is:

```
EXCEPTION: Error:Execution failed for task ':khroga:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
    '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero
    exit value 2 Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 2 mins
    28.672 secs Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaneg `multiDexEnabled` to`false`.